# Java Class.forName and obfuscated names, java fail to find class

Tags: java, class, reflection, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have .jar file with not common obfuscated names, obfuscated class looks like: 
`nul.goto. ...\\.. .final.` (NOTE: this first gap isn't normal space, it's no-break space) 
I can't get this class by Class.forName 
I make my own version of code with obfuscation like that, and it don't work even if I use `Class.forName(SomeClass.class.getName())` (it's just code to test) after obfuscation java will throw error that it can't find this class.
How to get class like that?

Comment: why you need Class.forName if you know the Class object already?

Comment: @almasshaikh this is just example and my test, real code use normal String to access other class. But even this code don't work.

Comment: I guess this case must be described in the documentation of your obfuscator.

Comment: @JBNizet I use ProGuard, and this works fine if I use normal configuration, with packages names like a.b.c, not some weird symbols and empty names.

Comment: If you are using ProGuard, you can define a class to not be obfuscated. This definitely going to work then

Comment: @user3558040 I know, I can even change configuration to use random names instead of weird spaces, but I need solution if I don't have access to .jar and I want get .class from it.

Comment: Did you try calling `loadClass` on a `ClassLoader`?

Comment: a bit late for a reply, but after playing around with this again recently: it works with ClassLoader, and in new java version such class will not load at all and just throw `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name` so I guess they "fixed" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some time I decided to go back to this, I used code like this for testing:
`pckg.Main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<ObfuscateMe> obfuscateMeClass = ObfuscateMe.class;
    System.out.println("Class name: `" + obfuscateMeClass + "`");
    try {
        System.out.println("Class.forName: " + Class.forName(obfuscateMeClass.getName()));
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) { System.out.println("Can't find class using Class.forName: `" + obfuscateMeClass.getName() + "`"); }
    try {
        System.out.println("ClassLoader.loadClass: " + Main.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(obfuscateMeClass.getName()));
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) { System.out.println("Can't find class using ClassLoader.loadClass: `" + obfuscateMeClass.getName() + "`"); }
}
```

Obfuscated with ProGuard:

```
-injars 'B:\Java\ProGuardTestApp\test.jar'
-outjars 'B:\Java\ProGuardTestApp\testObf.jar'
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-classobfuscationdictionary 'B:\Java\ProGuardTestApp\obfs.txt' # contains just one line "final"
-repackageclasses 'nul.goto. ...\\.. .final.'
-ignorewarnings
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

First I noticed that this no longer is a problem in java 11: class like that will just fail to load with error:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class pckg.Main
    java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal class name "nul/goto/▒///\\// /final//final" in 
class file pckg/Main
```

But there is still inconsistency between `forName` and `loadClass`, `forName` would still throw `ClassNotFoundException` but `loadClass` with throw `ClassFormatError` instead. OpenJ9 throws `ClassFormatError` in both cases.

On java 8 hotspot it works fine, and just like @Holger suggested in comment, version with ClassLoader works just fine. So I decided to dig a bit a find out why.
In class loader it just goes to very simple piece of code inside `URLClassLoader`: `name.replace('.', '/').concat(".class");` and just load that class from jar without any issues via native method `defineClass`.
But `Class.forName` goes directly to native method and validates class name: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/java/lang/Class.c

```
if (VerifyFixClassname(clname) == JNI_TRUE) {
    /* slashes present in clname, use name b4 translation for exception */
    (*env)->GetStringUTFRegion(env, classname, 0, unicode_len, clname);
    JNU_ThrowClassNotFoundException(env, clname);
    goto done;
}

if (!VerifyClassname(clname, JNI_TRUE)) {  /* expects slashed name */
    JNU_ThrowClassNotFoundException(env, clname);
    goto done;
}
```

So all `.` are changed to `/` and then in `VerifyClassname` we can find this:

```
if (slash_okay && ch == '/' && last_ch) {
    if (last_ch == '/') {
        return 0;       /* Don't permit consecutive slashes */
    }
}
```

src: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/native/common/check_format.c#l155

And that prevents class from loading.